# calculating percentage in Javascript.

Tags: javascript, math, percentage

Following code running fine. `SecondNumVal` is 25, but its giving 100% on 20 marks and 125% on 25 marks in `percentVal`. I can't find the error why its not giving 100% on 25 marks and 80% on 20 marks.

```js
$('#marks').on('change', '.obtmark', function() {
  var SecondNumVal = "25";
  $mark = $(this)
  var firstNumVal = $mark.val();
  // Find the tr this control is in and the corresponding percentage field
  $row = $mark.closest('tr')
  $pct = $row.find('.percentage')
  percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100
  pct = parseInt(percentVal) + '%';
  $pct.val(pct).attr('readonly', true);

  $studentgrade = $row.find('.grades')
  $remarks = $row.find('.remark')
  if (percentVal >= 90 && percentVal <= 100) {
    calculatedgrade = "A+";
    remark = "Excellent";
  } else if (percentVal >= 80 && percentVal < 90) {
    calculatedgrade = "A";
    remark = "Very Good";
  } else if (percentVal >= 70 && percentVal < 80) {
    calculatedgrade = "B";
    remark = "Good";
  } else if (percentVal >= 60 && percentVal < 70) {
    calculatedgrade = "C";
    remark = "Good";
  } else if (percentVal >= 50 && percentVal < 60) {
    calculatedgrade = "D";
    remark = "STY";
  } else if (percentVal >= 40 && percentVal < 50) {
    calculatedgrade = "E";
    remark = "USTY";
  } else if (percentVal < 40) {
    calculatedgrade = "F";
    remark = "Fail";
  }
  $studentgrade.val(calculatedgrade).attr('readonly', true);
  $remarks.val(remark).attr('readonly', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name='obtmarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control obtmark' type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
    <td><input name='percentage[]' placeholder='' class='form-control percentage' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
    <td><input name='grade[]' placeholder='' class='form-control grades' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
    <td><input name='remarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control remark' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: With the results it seems there is some mix up with numerator and denominator. Can you please add logging for `firstNumVal`?

Comment: Which element is `#marks`?

Comment: As a side note: There's no such thing as calculating percentage in `jQuery`. It's just a library that makes use of `Javascript`. You should tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Also you could easily extract the mathematical part to a pure function that doesn't care about the DOM, and use that in the DOM update callback.

Comment: I didn't found any problem with code you had posted, may be issue is somewhere else, please keep in mind, you have to convert all your input values by using parseInt because those are string values to be specific, if you do so then it will automatically works fine to all web browsers. but if you didn't then behavior may be different. please test your code in chrome, and if tested in chrome then in firefox to make sure.

Comment: @sorabh86 i have tested the code in both browsers. in percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100, firstNumVal will be given by user in input box named obtmarks. Its if user enters 20 marks it should display 80 as (20/25)*100=0.8*100=80,,but its showing 125%

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal i am getting firstNumVal from inputbox named as obtmarks

Comment: Are you sure you are doing firstVal / secondVal and not the other way around i. e. secondVal / firstVal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I am getting exact output if i enter 25 as input it is giving correct output as 100% pls go through attached picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92XmC.png)
    *This code is working.Change your selection*

```
$('.obtmark').change( function() {
      var SecondNumVal = "25";
      $mark = $(this)
      var firstNumVal = $mark.val();
      // Find the tr this control is in and the corresponding percentage field
      $row = $mark.closest('tr')
      $pct = $row.find('.percentage')
      percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100
      pct = parseInt(percentVal) + '%';
      $pct.val(pct).attr('readonly', true);

      $studentgrade = $row.find('.grades')
      $remarks = $row.find('.remark')
      // calculatedgrade="";
      // remark="";
      if (percentVal >= 90 && percentVal <= 100) {
        calculatedgrade = "A+";
        remark = "Excellent";
      } else if (percentVal >= 80 && percentVal < 90) {
        calculatedgrade = "A";
        remark = "Very Good";
      } else if (percentVal >= 70 && percentVal < 80) {
        calculatedgrade = "B";
        remark = "Good";
      } else if (percentVal >= 60 && percentVal < 70) {
        calculatedgrade = "C";
        remark = "Good";
      } else if (percentVal >= 50 && percentVal < 60) {
        calculatedgrade = "D";
        remark = "STY";
      } else if (percentVal >= 40 && percentVal < 50) {
        calculatedgrade = "E";
        remark = "USTY";
      } else if (percentVal < 40) {
        calculatedgrade = "F";
        remark = "Fail";
      }
      $studentgrade.val(calculatedgrade).attr('readonly', true);
      $remarks.val(remark).attr('readonly', true);
    });
```

Comment: same result. when user input 25 marks in inputbox its calculating as 125% in percentage inputbox.

Comment: for me when i enter 25 in first input box i am getting 100% .Pls check it

Comment: pls find the js fiddle link